# Files deleted on SVN repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I deleted files on SVN repository. If others do the svn update, will their local files also be deleted in sync with the repository? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will be removed in the working copies unless the users have No Access permissions on the removed items.